# eclipse on ubuntu 17.10 - toolbar drop down menus and pop ups moved when using dual monitor set up

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10

When I use eclipse oxygen on Ubuntu 17.10 with a dual monitor set up, the drop down menus and the pop ups from the toolbar are moved downwards:

[image: eclipse - drop down menu]

[image: eclipse - pop up]

Additionally, on start up, the eclipse oxygen icon is not displayed centered, but on the upper left corner (this however happens independent on the number of monitors used):

[image: eclipse - start up icon]

I already tried reinstalling eclipse a couple of times. I also deleted the .eclipse folder and the eclipse workspace before reinstalling.

I could live with the start up icon not being centered, but the placement of the drop down menu is really annoying. Is there a way to fix this annoyance?